# rspec: Testing a module that is included in other classes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have two classes A and B with common behavior. Let's say I put the common stuff in a module that each class `include`s:

```
class A
  include C

  def do_something
    module_do_something(1)
  end
end

class B
  include C

  def do_something
    module_do_something(2)
  end
end

module C
  def module_do_something(num)
    print num
  end
end
```

(To begin with, is this a reasonable way to structure the classes/modules? From a Java background, I would have made C an abstract class that A and B both inherit from. However, I've read that Ruby doesn't really have a notion of an abstract class.)

What is a good way to write tests for this?

- I could write tests for C, to specify its behavior for any class that `include`s C. However, then my tests for A and B would only test the behavior that isn't in C. What if A's and B's implementations change so that they no longer use C? This just kind of feels funny because my description of A's behavior is split across two test files.
- I could write tests only for A's and B's behavior. But then they will have a lot of redundant tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks like a reasonable way to structure your code in Ruby. Typically, when mixing-in a module, you would define whether the module's methods are class or instance methods. In your example above, this could look like

```
module C
  module InstanceMethods
    def module_do_something(num)
      print num
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your other classes, you would specify

```
includes C::InstanceMethods
```

(includes is used for InstanceMethods, extends is used for ClassMethods)

You can create tests in rspec using shared examples.

```
share_examples_for "C" do
  it "should print a num" do
    # ...
  end
end

describe "A" do
  it_should_behave_like "C"

  it "should do something" do
    # ...
  end
end

describe "B" do
  it_should_behave_like "C"

  it "should do something" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Example adopted from [here](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Example/ExampleGroupMethods/it_should_behave_like). And [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1835666) is another discussion site with some more info on shared examples.